Dell Inspiron 15 3537 not booting just beeps
I was using my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 3537) then a virus hit my device and the screen froze. When I restarted the device it didn't even show Dell logo, it just kept beeping, a single beep, but repeating.
I searched online to find out it's a BIOS issue but I don't know how to solve it. What can be done?

You found it's a bios issue - did where you find this tell you how to fix this generic issue? How is the virus related to a bios issue?

A 1 beep POST code could mean an issue with the BIOS ROM, but it specifically means a Possible System Board Failure. While possible a virus could cause hardware damage to a motherboard, it's highly improbable in this context - the simplest, and most likely, answer is if the laptop wasn't dropped, didn't fall, and didn't receive an electrical surge, motherboards fail, and they can fail for a wide variety of reasons with the answer likely to never be discerned. You can try a hard reset, but if that doesn't work, the motherboard likely needs to be replaced.

(Cont'd...) To perform a hard reset: unplug the AC adapter, unplug the battery, then repeatedly press the power button for 30s to discharge all capacitors. Reconnect the battery and the AC adapter, then power it on. If the POST code is still 1 beep, try booting it directly to hardware diagnostics by powering off and holding Fn while powering on - if it boots to Diagnostics, once at the selectable test GUI, tick the box for "Thorough Test" and run them all, rebooting once all are run. If that doesn't resolve and it's in warranty, contact tech support, else look for a used motherboard on eBay.
